# Move <input> datas between different pages

Tags: php, html

In the same server, I have a page called `mkwars` and another called `generatedtab`. Inside mkwars I have a lot of input fields that contains numeric numbers.I need to transfer the datas from those inputs, to another new inputs located in the page `generatedtab`.

This is the HTML code:

```
<table border="0" id="table1" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="50%" valign="top"><b>Home Clan:</b> <input type="text" id="clan1" name="clan1" onchange="nomewar();"/></td>
<td><b>Opponent Clan: </b> <input type="text" id="clan2" name="clan2" onchange="nomewar();"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

//other code

<form method="post" action="savewar.php">
<input type="submit" Value="Generate Table" style="height:70px;width:800px" />
</form>
```

And here you can see the PHP file:

```
<?
$percorso = file("war/filedb.txt");
while(list(,$value) = each($percorso)){
list($clan1, $clan2) = split("[:]", $value);
$params["clan1"] = trim($clan1);
$params["clan2"] = trim($clan2);
#print results
echo $params["clan1"]." - ".$params["clan2"]."<br />";
}
?>
```

`war` is a folder inside my server. When I click the button Generate Table I can't see the file (war/filedb.txt). Could you help me? I thought that the PHP way was the better, but if you think that I should do something else, tell me.

Comment: And posting that data doesn't work for you?

Comment: Your PHP file does not save anything. You should use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: no, when I click "Generate" I see a white page

Comment: `list($clan1, $clan2) = split("[:]", $value);` pretty sure you can't do that...

Comment: I don't quite follow, but if all the `<input>`s are within a `<form>` that has a get or post action, they're automatically added to `$_GET[]`/`$_POST[]` on submit, and you could call $_POST['clan1']` for example.

Comment: `split` split is depreciated ....

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do, but you use $_POST and $_GET globals to move data from a form to a script. I would also suggest, that if it is important for you to store the data - use a mysql database instead of textfiles. If you're only interested in doing some calculations live on page, use javascript instead of server side scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to do here. I *think* you want to fill out the html form and have the php script save the new input into a file on the server, and then print out the contents of the file. If that's correct, here are a few things you need to fix.

1) On your html page, the `<form>` tag must enclose all of the input fields you want to post back to the server. so:

```
<form method="post" action="savewar.php">
<table border="0" id="table1" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="50%" valign="top"><b>Home Clan:</b> <input type="text" id="clan1" name="clan1" onchange="nomewar();"/></td>
<td><b>Opponent Clan: </b> <input type="text" id="clan2" name="clan2" onchange="nomewar();"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" Value="Generate Table" style="height:70px;width:800px" />
</form>
```

2) In your php script, you need to use the superglobal $_POST or $_REQUEST variable to catch the data from the posted form. For example:

```
$clan1 = $_POST['clan1'];
$clan2 = $_POST['clan2'];
```

3) In your php script, you need to open the file for writing and append the new data to the end of the file:

```
$fileappendpointer = fopen("war/filedb.txt",'a');
$newline = $clan1 . " - " . $clan2 . "<br>";
fwrite($fileappendpointer, $newline);
```

4) Then you can easily read out the contents of the file:

```
fclose($fileappendpointer);
$filereadpointer = fopen("war/filedb.txt",'r');
$contents = fread($filereadpointer,filesize("war/filedb.txt"));
fclose($filereadpointer);
print $contents;
```